# AWS DynamodbStreams: Enable DynamodbStream on existing table using Template/CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-streams

I have an existing table in dynamodb on which the Stream is not enabled.
Is there a way to enable stream on this pre-existing table using cloudforamtion script?

Comment: I just encountered the same problem, I found this article but don't have a solution yet
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=217897

Comment: I also have same issue. is there any solution to this yet?